# Google charts not showing at first request, but on second only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I'm using Google charts to visualise company performance data. My Javascript looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart","line","geochart"], "callback": drawAllCompanyCharts});

    function drawAllCompanyCharts() {
        drawChart();
        drawLineChart();
        drawDonutChart();
        drawStackedChart();
        drawMarkersMap();
        drawChart();
    }
</script>
```

When a user clicks the button to show the charts page, nothing is shown and a

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

error appears. When clicking the button again, the charts appear as requierd, no errors.

I tried to use `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAllCompanyCharts);` as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/library_loading_enhancements), but `drawAllCompanyCharts()` never gets called. Also putting it in a `$(document).ready(function () {` didn't make it work.

The error clearly indicates that the google object is not ready by the time I need it. So it's all about timing. 
How can I assure `drawAllCompanyCharts()` will only be called when the google object is ready? And why doesn't `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawAllCompanyCharts);` show any effect?

Any help is highly appreciated :-)

Comment: do you also load another API (e.g. the Maps-Javascript-API)? End when you do...how do you load it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try load your `https://www.google.com/jsapi` after your js code. This happened sometime that object not found if we load js earlier than code.

So try interchange there position.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart","line","geochart"], "callback": drawAllCompanyCharts});

  function drawAllCompanyCharts() {
      drawChart();
      drawLineChart();
      drawDonutChart();
      drawStackedChart();
      drawMarkersMap();
      drawChart();
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Or you can add timeout for request to google function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout( function() {
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart","line","geochart"], "callback": drawAllCompanyCharts});

  function drawAllCompanyCharts() {
    drawChart();
    drawLineChart();
    drawDonutChart();
    drawStackedChart();
    drawMarkersMap();
    drawChart();
  }
}, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Dipak. Loading my javascript first and google charts thereafter didn't change anything. But setting a timeout like in your second approach made it finally work. Still curious why google.setOnLoadCallback() won't do anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sometime google api load asynchronously you can see such behaviour in google map some time